# How to write text from file to a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, text

I want to write code were the user is asked to write the name of a file. Then I want to analyze the file's content for a symbol, let's say `'e'`.

My problem is that I don't know how to start analyzing the file the correct way so that the content can be checked.

```
int main() {
    char c[1000], file_name[1000];
    int i;
    int s = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    gets(file_name);

    if ((fp = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);

    }

    if (fp) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", c) != EOF) {
            printf("%s", c);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        for (i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
            puts(c);
            if (c[i] == 'e') {
                ++s;
            }
        }

        printf("\nWhite spaces: %d", s);
        _getche();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: by "write", do you mean "read"?

Comment: Well to save the contents of the file to a string so i can run c[i]

Comment: you will need a char* where you will store all the content. Then, inside your while loop, do `strcat(myFullString, c);` this will append the new content to the "myFullString" array and you will then be able to use is in your for loop
Look at this example: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-concatenate-strings

Comment: I must add a char pointer if i understand correctly ? I am verry sorry i am verry new to C and programing at all, but i am very passionate about it.

Comment: Are you looking for `fread()` ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ Try `fread(c,sizeof(char),1000,fp);` Remember that in this case, `c` is an array of char, not a string. If you want `c` to remain a string : `fread(c,sizeof(char),999,fp);c[999]='\0';`

Answer (score 2):

```
char line[512]; /*To fetch a line from file maximum of 512 char*/
rewind(fp);
memset(line,0,sizeof(line)); /*Initialize to NULL*/
while ( fgets(line, 512, fp ) && fp !=EOF)
{

/*Suppose u want to analyze string "WELL_DONE" in this fetched line.*/

  if(strstr(line,"WELL_DONE")!=NULL)
  {
    printf("\nFOUND KEYWOD!!\n");
  }
  memset(line,0,sizeof(line)); /*Initialize to null to fetch again*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If its just a symbol you're looking for, or a *char*, you can simply use getc() :

```
int c;
....
if (fp) {
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == 'e') {
            // Do what you need
        }
    }
```

Or, alternatively, if it's a word you're looking for, fscanf() will do the job:

```
int c;
char symb[100];
char symbToFind[] = "watever";  // This is the word you're looking for
....
while ((c = fscanf(fp, %s, symb)) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(symb, symbToFind) == 0) {  // strcmp will compare every word in the file
        // do whatever                    // to symbToFind
    }
}
```

These alternatives will allow you to search every char or string in the file, without having to save them as an array.